# Laravel's Artisan::call() doesn't work with flag parameters

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface

My command works when I run it on the command line :

```
php artisan my:command --theFlag
```

But when I try to use it in code :

```
Artisan::call("my:command --theFlag");
```

Laravel cannot find my command :

```
Exception : The command "my:command --theFlag" does not exists
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I have found out : I guess my Laravel is a bit old and doesn't support this syntax.

This works :

```
Artisan::call("my:command", [
    "--theFlag" => true
]);
```